# How to print wget output to a file

Tags: wget

I'm trying to print http headers to a text file. I tried :

```
wget -S --spider -O SESSIONS.txt 'mysite.com'
wget -S --spider 'mysite.com'   > SESSIONS.txt
```

In both cases SESSIONS.txt remains empty. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"--spider" option does not download anything.

You can try this -

wget -S --spider -q mysite.com 2>Sessions.txt

This will save only the headers to "Sessions.txt"
However, you will have to use echo and other commands to figure out which request generated which headers.

Or, you can remove the -q option and then parse the file to remove unnecessary lines.

Another way is to use "curl -I". However, this sends a HEAD request instead of a GET request. So, it will only work if the server supports and responds to HEAD requests.